# how to validate mobile number using laravel regex

Tags: regex, laravel-5

I Have to validate mobile number using laravel 5.4 regex.

Valid Number Formats are given bellow : ( Total 13 characters )

```
88015xxxxxxxx 
88016xxxxxxxx
88017xxxxxxxx
88018xxxxxxxx
88019xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: what have you tried ? How did it fail ?

Comment: Can you please write which regex do you have that it doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below regex

```
$re = '/8801[5-9]{1}[0-9]{8}/';
$str = '8801511111111
8801600000000
8801712121221
8801898898999
8801999999999';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

First we are taking **8801** as it is.

Then **[5-9]{1}** It will check for numbers from **5 to 9** of length **1**.

Then **[0-9]{8}** It will check for numbers from **0 to 9** of length **8**.

You can test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/lYN39X/2).

Comment: Please check if it invalidates for input like "abcd8801999999999" ? Does it invalidate it?

Comment: How can i apply for in this case

88016xxxxxxxx
88018xxxxxxxx

Comment: It is already applying using [5-9]{1}. Do you have any issue?